# git fails on symlinks to my repo

Tags: git, ssh

I created a local git user with repos inside `/opt/git/repo1.git/`, `/opt/git/repo2.git/` etc. I setup public key auth and I can access my git repos over ssh as follows: `git@ubuntu:/opt/git/repo1.git`. When I set it up, I made a symlink in git's home dir that points to repo1:

```
ln -s /opt/git/repo1.git ~/
```

so I at first I was able to access my repo as `git@ubuntu:repo1.git`, but suddenly it stopped working now (not sure what's changed on my ubuntu box, perhaps some update was installed only). I get this error with tortoise git when I try to do `git pull`:

```
git.exe pull --progress --no-rebase -v "origin"

fatal: 'repo1.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I still can access it by using `git@ubuntu:/opt/git/repo1.git`, but why access by symlink stopped working and what can I do to debug it? As a side node, symlink in /home/git/repo1.git still exist and it points to the right location. I'm absolutely sure that it used to work, because when I cloned my repo on windows box I cloned it using the shorter symlink, I've done a few pulls and pushes since then, but suddenly everything stopped working with symlinks: I cannot access existing repo and I cannot clone new copies.

**Edit**: I also noticed that I still can do local git clone using symlink, but only if I do it from local terminal (e.g. if I try to do that from ssh session it would fail, perhaps because ssh detects that I'm trying to do ssh login second time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to figure out, and it appears that I found reason for such strange behavior. For some reason, when using putty it started to login as my local username instead of user with name `git`.

On my windows I use `jdoe` as my local user name and my ubuntu has that same user. So, when I added `repo1.git` symlink inside `/home/jdoe` on my ubuntu everything started to work from tortoise git.

The reason for that behavior seems to be that tortoise git uses saved putty sessions to login to remote instead of using keys from pageant. When I deleted saved putty sessions and created a new one that logs in as `git@ubuntu` then tortoise git also started to work without creating symlinks in `/home/jdoe`

**Edit**: after digging for details, it appears that the reason for the failure is in [TortoiseGit]Plink.exe:

```
Plink: command-line connection utility
Release 0.67
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
       ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
```

In my case saved putty session was called `ubuntu`, just like the host name. That's exactly why I was getting the issue.